# Reading the local TV provider name from the channel list content provider

Tags: google-tv

I recently started working on apps for Google TV. Can anyone please help me to get the local TV provider name from the channel list content provider.I can get the channel list from this content provider but not the TV provider name like Comcast, Dish, DirecTV etc through code.